# Windows Phone - Create AppBarButton Style for Button

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, application-bar

I need to display a Button with the same style as an AppBarButton. I use the same icon as in the AppBar, for example a floppy disk, but I need to create the circle around the icon dynamically.

How can I create a Style for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at Coding4Fun toolkit's RoundButton
http://coding4fun.codeplex.com

Comment: This is nice! Can I extract the control from the Toolkit, because I already use the WP Toolkit and only need this one control?

Comment: I'm note entirely sure, but the toolkit license is Ms-PL, so I guess it should be ok...

Comment: yes you can extract the control. Source is provided.. however i'd advise you to just take the assembly its not heavy and you don't need to maintain code :)

Comment: Okay, does it work with the new Windows Phone Toolkit, because it has a dependency for the Silverlight Toolkit? Should I install the whole Package via NuGet or just a .DLL for the control?

Comment: I haven't used it in WP8 however toolkit is also available for WP8 so give it a try... i'd say get both from nuget.. failing that exact what you need from source

Answer (score 0):

The below third party tool will help you to create largest collection of Metro style icons.

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio

I hope this may help you.